# Confused with C++ "simple" calculation with sign &

Tags: c++

I am looking at a C++ source code where there is what looks to be a simply calculation. Yet with no knowledge in C++, I can't quite understand how it is really calculated (my goal being making the same calculation under Excel).

```
uint64_t fpo = (((ui>>32) << 24) | (ui & 0xffffff)) + 0x123e00;
PrintAndLog("ui result : %lld [0x%llX]", ui, ui);
```

In my case, ui is 0x0F007057B9
and the result is 0xF8295B9

If I take the windows Calculator, I do (in Hex mode)

```
(0x0F007057B9 AND 0xffffff) + 0x123e00
```

I am getting the same result (expect for the first 0xF)

I have read somewhere that AND returns 1 if both bits of same "weigh" are 1
So if I take ui AND 0xffffff converted to Binary :

```
0x0F007057B9 0000111100000000011100000101011110111001
0xffffff                     111111111111111111111111
-------------------------------------------------------
             0000111100000000011100000101011110111001
```

Which does make any change...

Am I completely going to wrong way?? Sorry for my poor english, I am from South Korea.
Thank you for helping me {^^;

Comment: What is the type of `ui`

Comment: ui is defined earlier in the code as: void print88x(uint32_t hi, uint64_t ui)

Comment: Another way to write the same thing would be `ui / 0x100000000 * 0x1000000 + (ui % 0x1000000) + 0x123e00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For AND its

```
0 AND 0 = 0
0 AND 1 = 0
1 AND 0 = 0
1 AND 1 = 1
```

So if you AND a number with 0xffffff, you basicly just keep the numbers at those positions. You fill in the missing ones with 0.

In your case:

```
0x0F007057B9 0000111100000000011100000101011110111001
0xffffff     0000000000000000111111111111111111111111
-------------------------------------------------------
             0000000000000000011100000101011110111001
```

Im not sure, if that was your question tho :)

Comment: omg!! "You fill in the missing ones with 0" thank you so much!!

Comment: However I don't understand why it gives 0xF8495B9 with the code. And 0x8495B9 by hand. 
The result of the code is :
ui result : 260216249 [0xF8295B9]
Where does the "260216249" (which is the dec representation of the hex) and "F" come from?
Sorry I am not familiar with stackoverflow, I might need to create a new question (?)

Comment: Sorry, those are just too many unsorted numbers for me right now.
You dont need to create a new question, you can just edit your OP.

Maybe it helps, if you write down your whole calculation to spot the mistake.